# Shiny reactive value with radiobutton

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button, leaflet, choropleth

I am creating a Shiny app meant to display a choropleth map.

**I would like to change reactivly the values to show on my map with radiobuttons.**

It worked fine with normal button, but i am struggling with the radiobutton now, any ideas?

you can download the data via this link : https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/r/8b004f01-e7af-40d2-ab4a-8108a8bd24b2

here is my code so far :

```
sData <- readOGR(dsn = " Set your path to the downloaded Data here")

ui<- bootstrapPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, 
                right = 10,
                radioButtons("radio", h3("Indicateurs de mobilité"),
                             choices = list("AttrOne" = "Attr1",
                                            "AttrTwo" = "Attr2")))
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  v <- reactiveValues(data = sData$numdep)

  observeEvent(input$Attr1, {
    v$data <- sData $numdep
  })
  observeEvent(input$Attr2, {
    v$data <- sData $insee
  })



  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(sData) %>%  
      addProviderTiles(
           providers$"CartoDB.DarkMatter") %>%
      addPolygons(
           fillColor = ~colorBin(palette = "YlOrRd", 
                                 bins = getBreaks(v$data, 
                                                  nclass = 6, 
                                                  method = "fisher-jenks"),
                                 domain = v$data
                                 )(v$data),
           weight = 1,
           opacity = 0.3,
           color = "white",
           fillOpacity = 0.3)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one issue is that you are "listening" wrong your button, it should be the `id` you determined in you `ui`, in your case, "radio". Also, you can do the you with one `observeEvent` instead of your way;

```
    ui<- bootstrapPage(
      leafletOutput("mymap"),
      absolutePanel(top = 10, 
                    right = 10,
                    radioButtons("radio", h3("Indicateurs de mobilité"),
                                 choices = list("AttrOne" = "Attr1",
                                                "AttrTwo" = "Attr2",
                                                "AttrThree" = "Attr3")))
      )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {
  v <-  observeEvent(input$radio,{ 

     if(input$radio=="Attr1"){
         v$data <- Df$A1}
     if(input$radio=="Attr2"){
         v$data <- Df$A2}
     if(input$radio=="Attr3"){
        v$data <- Df$A4}
  })





  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(Df) %>%  
      addProviderTiles(
           providers$"CartoDB.DarkMatter") %>%
      addPolygons(
           fillColor = ~colorBin(palette = "YlOrRd", 
                                 bins = getBreaks(v$data, 
                                                  nclass = 6, 
                                                  method = "fisher-jenks"),
                                 domain = v$data
                                 )(v$data),
           weight = 1,
           opacity = 0.3,
           color = "white",
           fillOpacity = 0.3)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Despite of this bug, I cannot assure you this is going to work fine, because your example is not reproducible. Next time, please, may you provide us with a `dput(Df)` or at least some lines so we can execute your code from start to end and find any other problems?

WIth your code:

```
ui<- bootstrapPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, 
                right = 10,
                radioButtons("radio", h3("Indicateurs de mobilité"),
                             choices = list("AttrOne" = "Attr1",
                                            "AttrTwo" = "Attr2")))
  )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {
  v <- reactiveValues(data = sData$numdep)

observeEvent(input$radio,{ 

    if(input$radio=="Attr1"){
      v$data <- sData$numdep
      }
    if(input$radio=="Attr2"){
      v$data <- sData$insee
      }
  })

   output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(sData) %>%  
      addProviderTiles(
           providers$"CartoDB.DarkMatter") %>%
      addPolygons(
           fillColor = ~colorBin(palette = "YlOrRd", 
                                 bins = getBreaks(v$data, 
                                                  nclass = 6, 
                                                  method = "fisher-jenks"),
                                 domain = v$data
                                 )(v$data),
           weight = 1,
           opacity = 0.3,
           color = "white",
           fillOpacity = 0.3)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Best!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i've edited my question and my code with some data. It doesn't seem to work i get this error message when i run the code "Warning: Error in <-: cannot add bindings to a locked environment
  [No stack trace available]
Warning: Error in classInt::classIntervals: var is not numeric
  [No stack trace available]" Any idea?

Comment: Solved! the extra problem came from reactivity :   v <- reactiveValues(data = commData$Mobilite)
  
  observeEvent(input$radio,{ 
    
    if(input$radio=="Attr1"){
      v$data <- commData$Mobilite
      }
    if(input$radio=="Attr2"){
      v$data <- commData$Dependance
      }
  }) I've edited your answer